# iPhone 5.1 Simulator (retina) looks so big

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

I just upgraded Xcode from 4.2 to 4.3.3. I then launches iOS Simulator (with "Hardware -> Device" set to "iPhone (Retina)") and the simulator now appears so big that the app page has literally to be scrolled!! (previously it was just right ...no scrolling needed). Even the 'Home Page' in the simulator seems to need scrolling! Here's the screenshot...note that the 'home page' has the scroll bar in the right and bottom) ...why is this? Shouldn't it fit exactly and not need any scrolling?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a 17" laptop that is 1920x1200 resolution, the newest iPad has a resolution of 2048x1536.  The iPad actually had many more pixels in EITHER direction as my laptop.

The new simulator is DEFINITELY trying to show you all pixels, and most likely in a 1-to-1 fashion, which is most definitley going to take the simulator OFF SCREEN.

Pixel Density and total pixels is the answer!!!

Comment: How do I correct this? Yes, with a 'non-retina' mode, the iOS Simulator is fine (i.e. no scrollbar, and it all fits in one single view well). But, with a retina mode (because this is what I want to test with!), how can I adjust the pixels so that the scroll bar goes away? Any thoughts please?

Comment: In essence you cant unless you have a monitor that has MORE pixels that the device you are trying to emulate.  Sadly the answers are buy a 30" monitor (2560x1600), buy a new retina 15" macbook pro, or use the non-retina simulator.

Answer (score 27):

You can use Command-1 or Command-2 to scale your view down. Also you are able to change your device to non-Retina iPhone/iPad in Hardware-Device.

Comment: Yes, am able to change to non-retina mode (and in this non-retina mode, it is fine i.e. no scrollbar and all fits in one view). Any thoughts on how to tackle it in the retina-mode please?

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that the retina display simulator has a higher pixel density than your monitor but still attempts to show every pixel, so it has to take up more space.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your replies!