# UITableView as ScrollView Between Navigation and Tab Bars

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a table view laid out between a navigation bar and a tab bar and want to achieve scrolling only for the table view section (so in other words, in my iOS Simulator, I would want the two bars to always be seen, and I should be able to scroll my table view between them).

Having tried out various suggestions from SO posts, afraid am still getting something wrong. Can you advise please how do I fix this issue - I've been struggling with it for the last 1 day!

In the table view controller's viewDidLoad, I use the following code. Earlier, I also tried initializing a scroll view separately but understand that table view is a sub-class of scroll view, so ditched that path...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // To remove extra separators from the table view to prevent blank rows from showing.
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

    // ***** Scroll view implementation *****
    [[self tableView] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height - self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height)];
    [[self tableView] setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 2000)];

    [self setEdgesForExtendedLayout:UIRectEdgeNone];
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = YES;
}
```

In fact, to test this further, I have created a scroll view in a separate tab (in this tabbarcontroller app) where I only have a navigation bar and a tab bar so far (no table view). Its viewDidLoad looks like this - somehow, no luck there as well... the scroll bar starts from the top of the screen (rather than from the bottom of the navigation bar) and goes till the bottom of the screen (rather than till the top of the tab bar). So clearly I'm doing something conceptually wrong here... appreciate if you can help out please!!! The numbers put in here are experimental to test this out but I've ensured that the content size is larger than the scroll view frame...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, self.view.frame.size.width, 300)];

    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 1500)];
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];

    [self setEdgesForExtendedLayout:UIRectEdgeNone];
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
    [scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
}
```

Finally, when I debug my app in the simulator, what is odd is that for the table view tab, the scroll bar does appear momentarily to start from below the navigation bar. But as soon as I touch the track pad to scroll, it disappears and a more prominent scroll bar appears and starts from the top of screen to the bottom of the screen as I mention initially above!

Comment: In IB attribute inspector for the table view controller, deselect under top bars and under bottom bars so the table is between both. Comment out your other code.

Comment: Thanks  @RoryMcKinnel ... apologies but would you be aware how do I change the simulated metrics since I'm not using storyboards but rather developing the table view controller via code... Thanks much once again as I dont seem to be able to find how to change the IB attributes via the code!

Comment: I think you have the right code for setting the edges. That being the line `[set setEdgesForExtendedLayout:UIRectEdgeNone]`. If you are using a UITableViewController I would think that is all you need and none of the frame and content size setting as that should be handled by the table view when it lays out its cells.

Comment: Ok thanks. Somehow it still doesn't work - rather dazzled - will keep trying...

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the underlying error in my ways. More than an implementation bug, it was me missing out on a very basic issue...

In summary, the iOS Simulator would typically always have higher resolution / number of pixels than the computer screen, and no matter what, the simulator would always outsize the computer screen unless manually resized. So the scroll bar would usually be always present. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11265751/iphone-5-1-simulator-retina-looks-so-big) SO post helped me understand it.

On the other hand, the UIScrollView was automatically already implemented in my table view, given that UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView - I didnt have to do anything. I was scrolling the simulator with a 'light' double-touch, which was taking me to the scroll bar due to the issue mentioned above. If I 'hard-clicked' and then scrolled, then voila! The required UIScrollView did work properly as expected! This is probably what misled me to mention these statements in the question...!

---

*Finally, when I debug my app in the simulator, what is odd is that for the table view tab, the scroll bar does appear momentarily to start from below the navigation bar. But as soon as I touch the track pad to scroll, it disappears and a more prominent scroll bar appears and starts from the top of screen to the bottom of the screen as I mention initially above!*